# How to build a path in my templates file for Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

right now in my Django settings file for my project i am trying to build a path to so I can display my templates/projects/index.html file. Can I get help solving this?

```
    # Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

and in my TEMPLATES dictionary I have this is DIRS

```
`TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'projects/templates'),
        ],`
```

Comment: I noticed that you said `templates/projects` in your question but `projects/templates` in the code -- other than that, what is not working as expected? Any errors or unexpected behavior?

Comment: projects/templates/projects/index.html is how I am currently set up. I am getting a name error of NameError: name 'os' is not defined.

Comment: That can be solved by adding `import os` somewhere at the top of your file. You need to provide more detailed explanation of your problem(s) to be a suitable question for SO, see  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I answered this by updating the Templates.Dirs to:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',
            'projects/templates',
        ],
```